# Develop same app for different OSs

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8.1

What is the right (and best) workflow in order to develop the same app for iOS, Android and Windows Phone?

What about maintaining look and feel and also logic?

**Edit 1**

I usually start develop in Java (Android), and then "translate" the logic in iOS Objective-C. My only need is to know if someone has a better workflow or programming pattern.

Comment: If you know C#, Xamarin would be a good way to go https://xamarin.com/

Comment: @HaydenHolligan I know all three languages, but among them I prefer Java used in Android, which is the easiest for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty dependent on what type of app your creating and what languages you're comfortable with, but I would start with [this list](http://appindex.com/blog/ten-best-cross-platform-development-mobile-enterprises/) from late last year. I have never done cross platform development personally, but from different sources I've heard that Xamarian is a good choice, but definitely look at all your options.[Here's](http://thinkapps.com/blog/development/develop-for-ios-v-android-cross-platform-tools/) another, more recent list that might help and [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/mobile-app-development-vs.aspx) is another tool not listed in either of the previous links.

You should also make sure that cross platform development is really the best option for you before starting down this road. It might be the *fastest* way to do cross platform development, but you might not be able to implement all the features you're looking for. However, perpetuating "look", "feel", and "logic" will become exponentially more complex without using a cross platform IDE.